# Permission 0000 in /var/www/html through the sFTP

Tags: permissions, chmod

I can write in /var/www/html through the terminal in ssh, but to create a file by sftp through Filezilla, the file created have permissions 000.

How do I fix this? My problem is with these permissions, I want to create files by sFTP (filezilla) and I can not at all.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx and FastCGI and HHVM (I'm testing).

[image: Print Screen Filezilla File List]

[image: /var/www]

[image: /var/www/html]

Comment: Can you show the file permissions of `html` dir in `/var/www`? I wonder if you are missing the sticky bit. `chmod +s /var/www/html` `ls -l /var/www/html`

Comment: Edited the question and added the 2 images. Now you can see file list `/var/www` and `/var/www/html`

Comment: what is ubuntu 4.14 ? did you mean 14.04 ?

Comment: LOL - Ubuntu 14.04 ***, fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I came across this post, see if this helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/228396/how-to-setup-sshs-umask-for-all-type-of-connections

Add these lines to: `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

```
# Setting UMASK for all ssh based connections (ssh, sftp, scp)
session    optional     pam_umask.so umask=0027
```

You might also need to add them to: `/etc/pam.d/login`

---

Edit: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the `-u` flag to set the umask value.

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 0002
```

Restart ssh to have the changes take affect:

```
service ssh restart
[OR]
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Comment: I had done this, I tried again and it still fails.

Comment: See if the above helps out, I'm believe something in your setup is setting a umask of 0777 which creates files with an octal permission value of 0000: no permissions to read, write or execute.

Comment: I still can not, I'll keep trying until I succeed. This is very strange and bizarre because I've done it other times and never had this strange problem.